# Nuxtjs: Access the data of the component from anonymous middleware

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

how can we access the data of the component (such as infos, similarPosts [in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f8Du.png)) from the anonymous middleware in the nuxtjs application?

Comment: yes, maybe if we force it, we can do it in other ways (using vuex or something) but I want to do it directly.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have access to `data` in a middleware since it's run before the `data` is binded to the page as seen in the [lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle) of Nuxt.

Meanwhile, you could access `data` through `vm` thanks to [beforeRouteEnter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) or a similar router guard.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
asyncData(context) {
  // Do stuff with the context
  return {
    title: "My Title created from context"
  }
}
```

asyncData runs before loading the page component and will be called server side on the first request. This is what I was looking for, as I needed access to the context object while needing to set component variables before loading the component in the client.

Answer (score 0):

As [@kissu said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66319995/4992248), you can not do this, but as a workaround you can use Vuex. In this case it looks like:

```
middleware ({ store }) {
  const x = store.state.STORE_MODULE_NAME.STATE_PARAMETER_NAME
}
```